# Function to calculate an specific quantile of volume data from a list of tickers in environment

Tags: r, function, quantmod, quantile

I'm trying to calculate specific quartile number (in this example Q2) of column  data with the positive gap opening value of a stock list.

I try to explain you my approach:

Load my tickers list from a .csv file, create a list with all of them (OK)

```
library(quantmod)
Tickers <- read.csv("nasdaq_tickers_list.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

getSymbols(Tickers$Tickers,from="2018-08-01", src="yahoo" )
stock_data = sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts)
all_stocks <- do.call(list, mget(names(stock_data)[stock_data]))
```

I have the following function working fine to calculate the quartiles of a column (Stock_name.Postitivegap) and split them  into their corresponding quartile rank:

```
Posgapqrank <- function(x) {
stock_name <- stringi::stri_extract(names(x)[1], regex = "^[A-Z]+")
stock_name <- paste0(stock_name, ".Volqrank")
column_names <- c(names(x), stock_name)
x$posgapqrank <- as.integer(cut(x[, grep(".Positivegap", colnames(x))],quantile(x[,grep(".Positivegap",colnames(x))],probs=0:4/4),include.lowest=TRUE))
x <- setNames(x, column_names)
return(x)
}
```

Now I'd like a function to calculate an specific quantile of the same original data column , ".Positivegap" i.e. Q2

For that purpose I introduced the 0.25 in the quartile function, but getting error... any help here?

```
Q2 <- function(x) {
stock_name <- stringi::stri_extract(names(x)[1], regex = "^[A-Z]+")
stock_name <- paste0(stock_name, ".Q2")
column_names <- c(names(x), stock_name)
x$gapq2 <- as.integer(quantile(x[,grep(".Positivegap",colnames(x))],0.25)))
x <- setNames(x, column_names)
return(x)
}
```

Thank you very much for any comment.

## Let's make it simpler and start with a less complex example

```
getSymbols("SQ", from="2018-01-01", src="yahoo")
quantile(SQ$SQ.Volume, 0.25)
#How do I ad a new column to the SQ dataset with the Q2 volume data for each day?
```

Comment: Could you post the error message and some sample data using `dput` function?

Comment: I've just posted a very simple example for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: Based on SQ, what are you exactly trying to achieve? Aka what is the expected outcome? The 25% quartile (volume between 4234700 and 8926850), as a True / False flag?

Comment: What I'm exactly looking for is a new column, with the value of  25% quartile ( which is  8926850  for yesterday), but calculated for all the dates. In other words, the 25% quartile calculated for each day for volume.

Comment: Sounds like you want a rolling 25% quartile. But based on which n periods (10 days, 20 days)? The 8926850 is based on the whole period from 2018-01-01 until yesterday. Tomorrow is probably is the same number unless there is a new higher volume, which with todays price action might be the case.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly, I'd like to use the range of 2018-01-01. I know there are very low changes between consecutive days, but  to start I'd like to get a picture of all, then introduce some changes and make some correlation studies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created 2 functions. Q2 and rolling_Q2.

I tested them on the grep of the column name ".Volume" and both work. The Q2 function will calculate the Q2 from the whole dataset you give it. The rolling_Q2 will calculate the value of the Q2 based on a rolling window. Default 22.

```
Q2 <- function(x) {
  stock_name <- stringi::stri_extract(names(x)[1], regex = "^[A-Z]+")
  stock_name <- paste0(stock_name, ".Q2")
  column_names <- c(names(x), stock_name)
  x$gapq2 <- as.integer(quantile(x[,grep(".Positivegap",colnames(x))], 0.25))
  x <- setNames(x, column_names)
  return(x)
}


rolling_Q2 <- function(x, width = 22) {
  stock_name <- stringi::stri_extract(names(x)[1], regex = "^[A-Z]+")
  stock_name <- paste0(stock_name, ".Q2")
  column_names <- c(names(x), stock_name)
  x$gapq2 <- rollapply(x[,grep(".Positivegap",colnames(x))], width = width, FUN = function(x) as.integer(quantile(x, 0.25)))
  x <- setNames(x, column_names)
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: For .Volume column works perfectly. But, whey if I use with custom columns the result only takes in consideration 1 digit. So if the result should be i.e." 2.876 ", I get  only "2", how to indicate that I'd like 4 decimals in the result?

Comment: Remove the as.integer() in the formula's.

Comment: Easy fix. Thanks ;-)